# R Markdown - SparkTables not rendering

Tags: r, r-markdown, sparklines, sparktable

I am trying to render a sparktable using Rmarkdown. But the output always comes out in raw html or tex format. This depends on whether I am rendering a PDF or an HTML. Not sure what to do here?

```
library(sparkTable)
data("AT_Soccer")
content <- list(
   function(x) {sum(x)},
   function(x) {round(sum(x),2)},
   function(x) {round(sum(x), 2)},
   newSparkLine(lineWidth = 2,pointWidth = 6),
   newSparkBar()
)
names(content) <- c("Points","ShotGoal","GetGoal","GoalDiff","winLose")
vars <- c("points","shotgoal","getgoal","goaldiff","wl")
stab <- newSparkTable(AT_Soccer,content,vars)
export(stab, outputType = "html") ### For HTML R-Markdown files
export(stab, outputType = "tex") #### For PDF R-Markdown files
```

My output (for html files) looks like:

[image: Output]

The pdf output is:

[image: PDF output]

I am trying to get the actual sparktable. I have been able to render the actual table like this:

```
 showSparkTable(stab)
```

However, that opens the spark table within the Shiny framework. I'm trying to produce multiple rmarkdown documents with spark tables.

I took this example from: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015-1/templ-kowarik-meindl.pdf. Page 29.

### Solution for HTML

Setting this worked for me. Thanks to Martin. Still stuck on the pdf one though.

```
   knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = 'asis')
```

[image: HTML Fix]

Comment: Use chunk option `results = 'asis'`

Comment: This works when I knit to html, what about pdf? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use `outputType = "html"` if you want a PDF document?!  How about `outputType = 'tex'`?

Comment: I'm just trying to re-create the spark table in both HTML and PDF formats. I did make the outputType = 'tex' change when outputting PDF's but the sparktable doesn't render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*After studying the documentation a bit I summarize what I learned about including sparkTables inside Rmd documents:*

**1. For HTML documents** (`outputType = 'html'`):

Just as I said use the chunk option `results = 'asis'`.

---

**2. For PDF documents** (`outputType = 'tex'`):

You also need the option above in the case of PDF documents. **BUT** if you dont use it, you will see the plain LaTeX that is generated by `export()`.
At the very bottom of that output you will find an important hint:

```
## Information: please do not forget to add the following command before \begin{document} in your tex-fi
##
## \newcommand{\graph}[3]{ \raisebox{-#1mm}{\includegraphics[height=#2em]{#3}}}
```

So what we have to do here is to

- include that line of LateX in our preamble,
- add `results = 'asis'` to the code chunk,
- and set the argument `infonote` of `export()` to `FALSE`.

The last point prevents another error that the LaTeX compiler would throw (namely that we already have defined the command `\graph`).

What follows is a working example for a PDF document:

````
---
title: "Plotting Plots Under Code"
author: "Martin"
date: "February 1, 2017"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \newcommand{\graph}[3]{ \raisebox{-#1mm}{\includegraphics[height=#2em]{#3}}}
---


```{r setup, echo = F, warning = F, message = F, results = 'asis'}
library(sparkTable)
data('AT_Soccer')
content <- list(
   function(x) {sum(x)},
   function(x) {round(sum(x), 2)},
   function(x) {round(sum(x), 2)},
   newSparkLine(lineWidth = 2, pointWidth = 6),
   newSparkBar()
)
names(content) <- c('Points', 'ShotGoal', 'GetGoal', 'GoalDiff', 'winLose')
vars <- c('points', 'shotgoal', 'getgoal', 'goaldiff', 'wl')
stab <- newSparkTable(AT_Soccer, content, vars)
export(stab, outputType = 'tex', infonote = F)
```
````

[image]